# How to increase buffer size for RCurl's ftpupload function?

Tags: r, curl, ftp, rcurl

I'm using RCurl's ftpupload function to transfer files to Amazon s3 buckets. However, the files are getting truncated at 16KB.

[From the documentation, it seems like this is because CURL defaults to a max write size of 16kb.](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE.html) I see that I should be able to change the max buffer size. However, I don't know how to do so within RCurl.

I tried adding `curlSetOpt(.opts = list(upload.buffersize = '512kb'))` to my script, but am getting `Warning message: In mapCurlOptNames(names(.els), asNames = TRUE) : Unrecognized CURL options: upload.buffer.size`, and the files are still getting truncated. What's the right way to do this?

Thanks,

Robin